# What is the difference betwen “ESP8266Wifi.h” and “WiFiEsp.h” libraries?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I'll start a project using **NodeMCU V3 WiFi Module**, which uses **esp8266** chip. However, I am undecided as to which library to use. I don't want use a *serial bridge* with an arduino, I think it is better to use NodeMcu in *Standalone* *mode*.

So, here's my question: which library should I use? And, regarding the type of use, what is their difference? (**both libraries reference looks like the same for me**)

*p.s.: I also heard about the "WiFi.h" library. Does it work only on WiFi shields for arduino or does it also work on esp8266?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple:

- ESP8266WiFi.h - Runs on the ESP8266 to control the WiFi.
- WiFiEsp.h - Runs on an Arduino to communicate with an ESP8266 module with AT commands
- WiFi.h - Runs on an Arduino to work with the Arduino WiFi shield.

So the one you want, which is part of the ESP8266 core, is ESP8266WiFi.h.

Comment: Thanks! But let me ask you one more question: is the syntax the same for both libraries? At least in the examples I saw, they looked the same.

Comment: No idea. Probably only superficially of at all.